# What is the correct way to add .dll file in a MSVC 2010 project

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2010

I need to use the library **libMPSSE.dll** in my win32 console application project in MSVC 2010.  After writing the code I just copied the dll in the folder where my .cpp file is present. I am able to compile successfully but the issue is I am having linking error:

> libMPSSE.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot
>   read at 0x308

Is it really a problem with the dll itself or is there any problem with the dll path. How do we add dll to projects?

They have not provided any .lib file. The complete code is [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI/libMPSSE-SPI.zip)

Comment: I followed the instructions from this link (under Using post-build events), but still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

These are the usual steps to link to a DLL:

1. Include the DLL's header file in any of your source files that need to use functions from the DLL. You'll typically need to make sure that your build environment's include path contains the location of the header file. In the IDE you can do this using the *Additional Include Directories* configuration setting.
2. Pass the DLL's .lib file to the linker. In the IDE you do this by adding the .lib file to the *Additional Dependencies* setting. And you'll typically need to add the path to the .lib file to the *Additional Library Directories* setting.
3. Having done that, your program should compile and link. To make it run, you'll need to ensure that the DLL itself can be found at runtime. The simplest way to make that happen is to put it in the same directory as the executable file.

My guess, looking at your error message, is that in step 2 you passed the .dll to the linker rather than passing the .lib file.

Comment: teh vendor has not given me any .lib file, just one dll and one .a file

Comment: Well, talk to the vendor. I think .a is usually a static library. You want an import library (usually with .lib extension) to link against a DLL.

Comment: This is the link http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI/libMPSSE-SPI.zip : they have not provided any ..lib file

Comment: You asked how to link to a DLL. I told you how. I explained why you see that error message. Since you have not got a .lib file, your question becomes "How do I link to a DLL without a .lib file?" That's the next question that you should ask.

Comment: FTDI is a seriously screwed-up company.  Not sure what they do to their software engineers, sounds like they lock them up in a basement and throw food at them once in a while to keep them alive.  The smart ones do seem to manage to escape.  The supplied .a file is in fact a .lib file.  Just rename it.  Do expect more misery.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your comment saved me. +1

Answer (score 1):

As said here earlier you can't link to .dll files with C linker directly.
There're win32 APIs that can load the .dll file and return to you pointers to function.
Usually, .dll file is accompanied with .lib file contains code that does this burden for you and provides the API .dll file exposes. All you need is to link to this .lib file and put .dll file near the .exe file created.

Specifically regarding libMPSSE, it's said in its [release notes](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-I2C/ReleaseNotes_windows.txt) that you can rename the provided .a file to .lib file to link to it in Visual Studio (Project properties->configuration properties->Linker->Input). I tried it and it works as supposed.